# Blazor components: notify of collection-changed event causing thread collisions

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await, blazor

I am working on an ASP.NET Core Blazor application with .Net Core 3.0 (I am aware of 3.1, but due to Mordac I am stuck with this version for now).

I have a multiple-component page, and some of those components require access to the same data and need to all be updated when the collection is updated. I've been trying to use EventHandler-based callbacks, but those get invoked on their own threads at about the same time (if I [understand correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netcore-3.0)), causing the callbacks in the .razor components to attempt to make service calls to the context at the same time.

Note: I've tried making my DbContext`s lifetime transient, but I'm still getting the race conditions.

It's quite possible that I gotten myself into an async blender and don't know how to get out.

I've tentatively concluded that the `event EventHandler` methodology will not work here. I need some way to trigger "collection changed" updates to the components without triggering a race condition.

I've *thought* about updating the services involved in these race conditions with the following:

- Replace every search function with a publically bindable collection property
- Having every create/update/delete call update every single one of these collections

This would allow the components to bind directly to the collections that are changed, which I *think* will cause every binding to it in any component to update without the needing to be explicitly told, and this in turn would allow me to ditch the "collection changed" event handling entirely.

*But I'm hesitant to try this and haven't done it yet* because it would introduce a fair amount of overhead on each major service function.

**Other ideas?** Please help. If a collection has changed, I want Blazor components that rely on that collection to somehow be able to update, whether through notifications or binding or some other way.

The following code is a heavy simplification of what I've got, and it's still causing race conditions when the event handlers are invoked from the service.

Model

```cs
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
}
```

MyContext

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base()
    {
        Models = Set<Model>();
    }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Models = Set<Model>();
    }

    public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```

ModelService

```cs
public class ModelService
{
    private readonly MyContext context;
    private event EventHandler? CollectionChangedCallbacks;

    public ModelService(MyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void RegisterCollectionChangedCallback(EventHandler callback)
    {
        CollectionChangedCallbacks += callback;
    }

    public void UnregisterCollectionChangedCallback(EventHandler callback)
    {
        CollectionChangedCallbacks -= callback;
    }

    public async Task<Model[]> FindAllAsync()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(context.Models.ToArray());
    }

    public async Task CreateAsync(Model model)
    {
        context.Models.Add(model);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // No args necessary; the callbacks know what to do.
        CollectionChangedCallbacks?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs (excerpt)

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    string connString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    services.AddScoped<ModelService>();
}
```

ParentPage.razor

```cs
@page "/simpleForm"

@using Data
@inject ModelService modelService
@implements IDisposable

@if (AllModels is null)
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var model in AllModels)
    {
        <label>@model.Msg</label>
    }

    <label>Other view</label>
    <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>

    <button @onclick="(async () => await modelService.CreateAsync(new Model()))">Add</button>
}

@code {
    private Model[] AllModels { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool ShowForm { get; set; } = true;
    private object disposeLock = new object();
    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (disposeLock)
        {
            disposed = true;
            modelService.UnregisterCollectionChangedCallback(CollectionChangedCallback);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AllModels = await modelService.FindAllAsync();
        modelService.RegisterCollectionChangedCallback(CollectionChangedCallback);
    }

    private void CollectionChangedCallback(object? sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Feels dirty that I can't await this without changing the function signature. Adding async
        // will make it unable to be registered as a callback.
        InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            AllModels = await modelService.FindAllAsync();

            // Protect against event-handler-invocation race conditions with disposing.
            lock (disposeLock)
            {
                if (!disposed)
                {
                    StateHasChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ChildComponent.razor

```
Copy-paste (for the sake of demonstration) of ParentPage minus the label, ChildComponent, and model-adding button.
```

**Note:** I've also experimented with attempting to insert a block of code into the HTML portion of the component, but that didn't work either since I can't use an `await` there.

Possibly bad idea that I experimented with (and that still didn't avoid the threading collision):

```cs
    @if (AllModels is null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        @Load();
        @*
            Won't compile.
            @((async () => await Load())());
        *@
    }
    else
    {
        ...every else
    }

    @code {
        ...Initialization, callbacks, etc.

        // Note: Have to return _something_ or else the @Load() call won't compile.
        private async Task<string> Load()
        {
            ActiveChargeCodes = await chargeCodeService.FindActiveAsync();
        }
    }
```

Please help. I'm experimenting in (for me) uncharted territory.

Comment: Given that 3.0 has a very short support timeline and 3.1 is the long-term support version, you should be able to make a case to Mordac.  Good luck

Comment: Try to `ConfigureAwait(false)` all your tasks calls, eg `AllModels = await modelService.FindAllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Can you provide a simpler repro? To @Flydog57's point, .NET Core 3.0 support will end on March 3, 2020 - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: @Flydog57 Is .NET Core 3.1 a significant API update over 3.0 when it comes to ASP.NET Core applications? [A lot of the focus from 3.0 to 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.0-3.1) seem to be browser support and the removal of Windows Forms controls

Comment: @aguafrommars According to [this blog post from Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html),

"Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous practice. You would have to use ConfigureAwait(false) for every await in the transitive closure of all methods called by the blocking code, including all third- and second-party code. Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack). As the title of this post points out, the better solution is “Don’t block on async code”."

Comment: Hum ! He said in **Preventing the Deadlock** paraph :  
There are two best practices (both covered in my intro post) that avoid this situation:

* In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) **wherever possible**.
* Don’t block on Tasks; **use async all the way down.**

Comment: @aguafrommars Gotcha. I'm dealing with a race condition though, not deadlock. Two threads are trying to go for the same instance of the EF db context at the same time. Allowing this tells me that I've got a design problem. Working on it.

Answer (score 4):

Since i'm currently in a situation that looks awfully lot like yours, let me share what i found out. My issue was "StateHasChanged()". Since i've seen that call in your code too, maybe the following helps:

i got a pretty simple callback handler:

```
    case AEDCallbackType.Edit:
        // show a notification in the UI
        await ShowNotification(new NotificationMessage() { Severity = NotificationSeverity.Success, Summary = "Data Saved", Detail = "", Duration = 3000 });
        // reload entity in local context to update UI
        await dataService.ReloadCheckAfterEdit(_currentEntity.Id);
```

the notification function does this:

```
async Task ShowNotification(NotificationMessage message)
{
    notificationService.Notify(message);
    await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
}
```

the reload function does this:

```
public async Task ReloadCheckAfterEdit(int id)
{
    Check entity = context.Checks.Find(id);
    await context.Entry(entity).ReloadAsync();
}
```

The problem was the StateHasChanged() call. It tells the UI to re-render. The UI consists of a datagrid component. The datagrid calls a query in the dataservice, to fetch data from the DB.
This happens just right before "ReloadAsync" is called, which is "awaited". Once ReloadAsync actually executes, it happens in a different thread, causing the dreaded "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" exception.

My Solution was to remove the StateHasChanged line completely from where it was, and call it once after everything else was completed. No more concurrent caller issues.

Good luck solving this, i feel your pain.